# nested table in where clause does not work

Tags: arrays, oracle, plsql

I have a nested table in pl/sql and am trying to use it in where clause. My main idea is to read some meta data from user_tab_columns based on filter condition for only few certain tables, which the user needs to enter.
Here my code:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 100000
DECLARE
    TYPE tables_list IS
        TABLE OF VARCHAR2(128);
    tables_names tables_list := tables_list('TABLE_1', 'TABLE_2', 'TABLE_3');
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT
        table_name
    BULK COLLECT
    INTO arrayvalues_table
    FROM
        user_tab_columns a
    WHERE
        a.table_name IN (
            SELECT
                tables_names
            FROM
                TABLE ( tables_list ) t
        )
      --  MEMBER OF ( tables_list )
        ;
END;
/
```

But it brings the error message:

```
END;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 17, column 25:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "TABLES_LIST": invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 6, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

So, my table with values "TABLES_LIST" is not recognized.Neither as select from table(TABLES_LIST), nor as member of (commented out below). What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Even if you do it *right*:

```
No : FROM TABLE ( tables_list  ) t
Yes: FROM TABLE ( tables_names ) t
```

it won't work:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     TYPE tables_list IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (128);
  3
  4     tables_names       tables_list := tables_list ('TABLE_1', 'TABLE_2', 'TABLE_3');
  5     arrayvalues_table  SYS.odcivarchar2list;
  6  BEGIN
  7     SELECT DISTINCT a.table_name
  8       BULK COLLECT INTO arrayvalues_table
  9       FROM user_tab_columns a
 10      WHERE a.table_name IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE
 11                               FROM TABLE (tables_names) t);
 12
 13     FOR i IN 1 .. arrayvalues_table.COUNT
 14     LOOP
 15        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (arrayvalues_table (i));
 16     END LOOP;
 17  END;
 18  /
                             FROM TABLE (tables_names) t);
                                         *
ERROR at line 11:
ORA-06550: line 11, column 42:
PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements
ORA-06550: line 11, column 35:
PL/SQL: ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item
ORA-06550: line 7, column 4:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

So, either create type at SQL level, or use a built-in type (simpler option, I'd say):

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     tables_names       SYS.odcivarchar2list := sys.odcivarchar2list ('EMP', 'DEPT', 'TABLE_3');
  3     arrayvalues_table  SYS.odcivarchar2list;
  4  BEGIN
  5     SELECT DISTINCT a.table_name
  6       BULK COLLECT INTO arrayvalues_table
  7       FROM user_tab_columns a
  8      WHERE a.table_name IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE
  9                               FROM TABLE (tables_names) t);
 10
 11     FOR i IN 1 .. arrayvalues_table.COUNT
 12     LOOP
 13        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (arrayvalues_table (i));
 14     END LOOP;
 15  END;
 16  /
DEPT
EMP

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Works, eh?

Comment: Thanks, but when using your second proposal I got this error message:Error report -
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST
ORA-06512: at line 7
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: @MTO did you deleted your comment? Because it worked! I used in the where clause MEMBER OF, but with the table tables_names instead of tables_list, so I was very close at the begining. But why it works with MEMBER OF and not with select tables_names from table(tables_names)?

Comment: @kirilb what construction works with `member of` exactly?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use collections in an SQL statement (even if it is inside a PL/SQL block) then they must be declared in the SQL scope using the `CREATE TYPE` statement (or use an existing collection that has been declared in that scope).

If you are going to use collections in a PL/SQL block then they can be declared in either an SQL or a PL/SQL scope.

Apart from that, you need to declare the `arrayvalues_table` variable and make sure you refer to the names that you declare (rather than a similar but non-identical name).

So:

```sql
CREATE TYPE string_list IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(128);
```

Then:

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 100000

DECLARE
  table_names       string_list := string_list('TABLE_1', 'TABLE_2', 'TABLE_3');
  arrayvalues_table string_list;
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT
           table_name
    BULK COLLECT INTO arrayvalues_table
    FROM   user_tab_columns
    WHERE  table_name MEMBER OF ( table_names );
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=69a7b2ddfd13897faa131430316293e2)*